# Python equivalent to radical() in Sage?

Tags: python, enthought, sage, number-theory

I'm working on some code to generate the number of triples satisfying the ABC conjecture that are less than a given quality and within a specified integer range. I originally wrote my code in Sage, which has a radical() function built in.

I now need to figure out a way to perform the same task in Python, which I have as of yet been unable to do.

Any advice or resource recommendations on building a radical function, i.e. that given an integer will output the largest squarefree divisor of that integer?

Comment: Sage is written in Python and licensed GPL. Why not pull the relevant code from Sage? https://github.com/sagemath/sage

Comment: @JonathanMarch: it's not that easy. To compute the radical you need to factorize the number. Sage doesn't do this computation by itself but delegate the problem to some external package (Pari-GP by default).

Comment: FWIW it's quite simple to build a list of primes quite efficiently by sieve using numpy slicing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for anyone coming from Google or elsewhere who has this same question:

SymPy has something akin to Sage's radical function (which finds the squarefree part of a number n), you can use `sympy.ntheory.factor_.core(n, t=2)`.

As explained in the documentation [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#:%7E:text=sympy.ntheory.factor_.core(n%2C%20t%3D2)):

> Calculate core(n, t) = core<sub>t</sub>(n) of a positive integer n

Therefore, `core(n, 2)` gives you the same as `radical(n)` in Sage

Comment: They aren't actually the same. `radical` is the product of prime factors, while core takes the power of each factor modulo 2. So, `radical(p^k) = p` for prime number p, while `core(p^k) = p^(k mod 2)`.